Simulate paste from clipboard in Cypress Typescript
I ran into a hiccup when I tried to find solutions for simulating a paste event in Cypress Typescript. Most solutions I find are in Javascript and so far none are working. :/
The scenario: User clicks "Copy" button, then pastes the value into a text field.
I tried the following but they're not working (these are in JS but I need it to be in TS). Is there anything I'm missing to add? Currently none is working and I have been stuck for days already in this. Thank you!
Trial 1: (not working, added in commands.ts)
paste(input: string | { pastePayload: string; pasteType: string }): Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>,

Cypress.Commands.add('paste', { prevSubject: true }, (subject, pasteInput) => {
    const isSimpleText = typeof pasteInput === 'string';
  
    const pastePayload = isSimpleText ? pasteInput : pasteInput.pastePayload;
    const pasteType = isSimpleText ? 'text/plain' : pasteInput.pasteType || 'text/plain';
  
    const data = pasteType === 'application/json' ? JSON.stringify(pastePayload) : pastePayload;
  
    const clipboardData = new DataTransfer();
    clipboardData.setData(pasteType, data);
  
    const pasteEvent = new ClipboardEvent('paste', {
      clipboardData
    });
    subject[0].dispatchEvent(pasteEvent);
  
    return subject;
  });

Usage 1:
    cy.window().then(win => {
        win.navigator.clipboard.readText().then(classCodeFromClipboard => {
            let classCode = classCodeFromClipboard
            element.paste(classCode)
        })
    })

Trial 2: (not working)
element.trigger('paste')

Trial 3: (not working, tried from here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4eEc3x24D64)
cy.wrap(Cypress.automation('remote:debugger:protocol', {
    command: 'Browser.grantPermissions',
    params: {
        permissions: ['clipboardReadWrite', 'clipboardSanitizedWrite'],
        origin: window.location.origin,
    }
}))

cy.get('@copiedClassCode').then(copiedClassCode => {
    let copyClass = String(copiedClassCode)
    cy.window().its('navigator.permissions').invoke('query', {name: 'clipboard-read'}).its('state').then(cy.log)
    cy.window().its('navigator.clipboard').invoke('readText').should('eq', copyClass)
})

Trial 4: (not working)
element.type('{ctrl}', {release: false}).type('v')

Trial 5: (not working)
Cypress.Commands.add('paste', { prevSubject: true }, (selector: any, pastePayload: any) => {
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event
    cy.wrap(selector).then($destination => {
      const pasteEvent = Object.assign(new Event("paste", { bubbles: true, cancelable: true }), {
        clipboardData: {
          getData: () => pastePayload
        }
      });
      $destination[0].dispatchEvent(pasteEvent);
    });
  });

Usage 5:
    cy.window().then(win => {
        win.navigator.clipboard.readText().then(classCodeFromClipboard => {
            let classCode = classCodeFromClipboard
            element.paste(classCode)
        })
    })


What is your goal - to send a clipboard event to an element, or just to get clipboard text into an editable element (e.g input)?

Could also use some details about the code you posted - where does element come from, what type of element is it, what is .its('state') doing (fails to run). You have a lot of "not working" - what would be "working"?

@Josephine.Valentina I need to paste the copied value to an input (as per The scenario). Element is the editable element (). The .its('state') is if access to clipboard permission is allowed. Not sure what I am missing so all I tried is not working. I have a Copy button to copy a text, then I just need to paste it to any editable element to verify the value if it has been copied correctly. However, I cannot paste. Currently I'm stuck.

With the paste - does it have to be via an event? i.e are you testing that a paste event is handled correctly. Some code examples above don't have an event, so I would guess not - can you confirm.

I need to paste as per the test requirement if it's possible. If it's not, I think we can just check the value copied on the clipboard. :) For the next steps after verifying the value copied, I can use type if ever.

You can't do it any more (see Gleb's comments).
But you can use a stub if you just need to verify the value has been copied correctly.
cy.visit(myUrl, {
  onBeforeLoad: (win) => {
    cy.stub(win.navigator.clipboard, 'writeText').as('writeText')
  },
})
cy.contains('Copy text').click()
cy.get('@writeText').should(
  'have.been.calledOnceWith',
  Cypress.sinon.match.string,
)



I tried this one now, it's not working on my end. :/ not sure what I'm missing. I found something similar https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/spy-on-clipboard-copy/ using cy.window() but also not working. I'm getting expected writeText to have been called exactly once with arguments {test: function(){}, message: typeOf("string")}, but it was never called . :/ But I did found something that worked, thank you for the hint! ;)

@Faith probably a typo, I have the same passing result.

Can you share your code as well @Josephine.Valentina? I'm still having a failed result despite copying @Insusceptible 's code. I just changed the myUrl to '/' to access from baseUrl

expected writeText to have been called exactly once with arguments {test: function(){}, message: typeOf("string")}, but it was never called

Check for a typo, or perhaps you forgot to invoke the call that perfomes the copy.

Unfortunately to use the pattern Faith Berrya proposed, you need an older version of Chrome.
The current version blocks with a prompt to manually give permission, so it is not useful for automated testing.
For anyone following, you should instead use the stubbing pattern, which will also work cross-browser (Firefox, Safari).
This is the result I get running the test in the copy-to-clipboard repo



Found something here https://dev.to/walmyrlimaesilv/testing-copy-to-clipboard-with-cypress-1414 that worked for my scenario. Since paste cannot be done anymore, maybe we can use stub or spy on the value using other methods as suggested by you guys. Tried stub but didn't work, so I tried this one to access the clipboard value and voila, worked smoothly for my case :) Guess I'll just type the value into the text field since its value is verified correct already. Thanks guys for the awesome help! :)
Cypress.Commands.add('assertValueCopiedToClipboard', (value: any) => {
    cy.window().then(win => {
      win.navigator.clipboard.readText().then(text => {
        expect(text).to.eq(value)
      })
    })
  })

cy.assertValueCopiedToClipboard(copyClass)

Edit: I added this code to grant access permission to clipboard
cy.wrap(Cypress.automation('remote:debugger:protocol', {
    command: 'Browser.grantPermissions',
    params: {
        permissions: ['clipboardReadWrite', 'clipboardSanitizedWrite'],
        origin: window.location.origin,
    }
}))


